# Kubernetes failing with SSL error while Docker compose is working for Dotnet core project

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, docker-compose, kompose

I am new to Kubernetes and I am experimenting with some of these in my local development. Before I give my problem statement here is my environment and the state of my project.

1. I have Windows 10 with WSL2 enable with Ubuntu running through VS Code.
2. I have enabled the required plugins in VS Code (like Kubernetes, Docker and such of those)
3. I have Docker desktop installed which has WSL2 + Ubuntu + Kubernetes enabled.
4. I have ASP.Net Core 5 working version from my local system + ubuntu through Docker
5. I have dockerfile + docker compose file and I have tested them all with and without SSL port and those are working with SSL and without SSL as well. (for that I have modified the program to accept non-SSL request).

coming to docker file
-- It has required ports exposed like 5000 (for not SSL) and 5001 (for SSL)
coming to docker compose file
-- It has reuqired mapping like `5000:80` and `5000:443`

-- It also has environment variable for URLs like

```
ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+5001;http://+5000
```

-- It also has environment variable for Certificate path like

```
ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/https/aspnetapp.pfx
```

-- It also has environment variable for Certificate password like

```
ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=SECRETPASSWORD
```

Now, when I says `docker compose up --build` It build the project and also start the containers.
I am able to access the site through https://localhost:5001 as well as http://localhost:5000

Now, coming to kubernets
-- I have used kompose tool to generate kubernetes specific yaml files
-- I haven't made any change in that. I ran the command `kompose convert -f docker-compose.yaml -o ./.k8`
-- finally, I ran `kubectl apply -f .k8`

It starts the container but immediately failed. I checked the logs and it says the following:

```
crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
      Unable to start Kestrel.
      Interop+Crypto+OpenSslCryptographicException: error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file
         at Interop.Crypto.CheckValidOpenSslHandle(SafeHandle handle)
         at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.OpenSslX509CertificateReader.FromFile(String fileName, SafePasswordHandle password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)
         at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate..ctor(String fileName, String password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)
         at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2..ctor(String fileName, String password)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Certificates.CertificateConfigLoader.LoadCertificate(CertificateConfig certInfo, String endpointName)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.KestrelConfigurationLoader.LoadDefaultCert()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.KestrelConfigurationLoader.Reload()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.KestrelConfigurationLoader.Load()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.BindAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.StartAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Unhandled exception. Interop+Crypto+OpenSslCryptographicException: error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In "It has required mapping like `5000:80` and `5000:443`", actually it should be `5001:443` (as the port 5001 is used to map to the https 443 port).

Based on this error message

> "nterop+Crypto+OpenSslCryptographicException: error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file",

It seems the certificate file doesn't exist in the following location: `/https/aspnetapp.pfx`

Run the image, using the following Docker command:

```
docker run -it --entrypoint sh <image name>
```

You will access the container without running the entrypoint, do a `cd /https/`, check if the certificate is located in this folder or not, if not this is probably the problem.